# WinSCP - can it replace newer files with older files?

Tags: windows, php, winscp, rollback

I've been using the Windows app WinSCP for uploading the latest scripts in my PHP web app to my web server, using the comparison function within WinSCP which replaces older remote files with newer local files.

But, if I made a mistake and wished to replace newer files on the remote server with older files on the local server, is there anyway to do this using WinSCP? The options in the program only seem to allow for replacing old with new, and not the other way around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can manually drag and drop the files/folders from the source to the target folders. This can be done regardless of the location of the newer/older files.